# How to use multiple url with selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a scraper that extracts data from websites. However, I would like to scrape multiple links, not only one. However, I get an error when I try to use two urls on one chromedriver. I also tried putting it in seperate files but that also does not work. Is there a way to do this?

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import os

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)

url = "https://www.google.com"
wd.get(url)
table = WebDriverWait(wd, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'live-table')))
soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')
        
url2 = "https://www.flashscores.com"
wd.get(url2)
table2 = WebDriverWait(wd, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'live-table')))
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(table2.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try using a for loop to iterate over a list of urls

```
def main(url):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)

    wd.get(url)
    table = WebDriverWait(wd, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'live-table')))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')

urls = ["google.com","facebook.com","instagram.com"]

for i in urls:
    main(i)
```